# how mobile (android) apps communicates securely to backend servers?

Tags: android, security, mobile

I had developed an android app, and my backend server as well.

The server is providing REST-ful services for the app to call. Some questions..

1) is this the correct way of doing things? say.. user login, get his inbox messages, etc, via REST?

2) how to communicate securely? so that if anyone who knows the URLs, they can attack the services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) is this the correct way of doing things? say.. user login, get his inbox messages, etc, via REST?

I wouldn't say that there's a "correct" way, but multiple ways, each with their pros and cons. Without additional detail, it sounds as if you're on the right track.

> 2) how to communicate securely? so that if anyone who knows the URLs, they can attack the services.

Really the only way is to use HTTPS. URLs are publicly accessible via the web, enabling folks to attack them. This is not much different than any other site/service, REST or SOAP. I don't know if there's a way to really lock down the traffic to only the devices, maybe registering a device id and requiring it on every request? That still doesn't stop an attack, but may be a simple way to reduce some of the noise.

Comment: hi. in fact i m noob to security. i thought if the devices send their id on every requests, anyone who has captured the ids, can still accessed restricted info via my REST isnt it?

Comment: No, they can't access any data via https. All data (including headers) travels using SSL or TLS, and unless someone is able to break these protocols (which can be done in some instances, but is very, very difficult) then you are fine. All your Datas is safe with us!

Comment: The only way they could access the device id when using SSL is if you put it in the URL (which is a bad idea).

Comment: correct me if i m wrong..i set every communications to be via https. and for every requests, append with the device id. the server upon receiving the REST request, check for valid device id. that's all?

Comment: @CaspNZ, I desperately need to know how to use headers while using GET and POST to a webservice, I have been using web services  without any knowledge of headers. Please help